# Métodos que exigem retorno mesmo tendo Void na "assinatura"

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Estou fazendo uns testes para entender na prática o funcionamento da classe[`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) no `swing`, e notei que o método `doInBackground` exige retorno `null`, mesmo iniciando  a variável da forma abaixo:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        return null;

    }
};
```

Ao declarar `SwingWorker<Void, Void>`, o primeiro parâmetro remete justamente o retorno do método citado, mas mesmo sendo `Void`, ele obriga a retornar `null`(se não informar o retorno nulo, a IDE acusa erro semântico e nem compila o código). Vejam executando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/vJyg5a).

Se a assinatura é `protected Void doInBackground()`, por quê exige retorno mesmo assim? Há alguma diferença entre `Void` e `void` que justifique este comportamento?

Comment: "ele obriga a retornar null" isso vem do compilador ou da IDE?

Comment: @rray a IDE acusa um erro semântico "missing return statement", e nem compila.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void` é a palavra chave usada para indicar que um método não retorna nada.
Por sua vez [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) é uma classe, logo, seguindo as regras, o compilador obriga que algo seja retornado.

[Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) é a versão *"boxing"* do "tipo primitivo"<sup>(1)</sup> `void`.
Como `void` indica ausência de valor também [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) não pode ser instanciada.

Quando um método tem na sua assinatura [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) como tipo de retorno, não podendo [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) ser instanciado, o método tem de retornar `null`(o que de alguma forma indica ausência de retorno/valor).

A classe [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) usa o seu primeiro tipo de parâmetro para indicar o tipo a retornar pelo método `doInBackground()`, quando não há nada para retornar é usado [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) para o tipo de retorno.
Genéricos só podem usar tipos referência.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> `void` **não é** um [tipo primitivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)</sub>

Comment: Então, no caso do SwingWorker, como quem define o tipo de retorno é quem está programando, ele obriga a usar o Void para que o método sempre tenha retorno, não importa o tipo que passemos?

Comment: O que obriga a que haja retorno é a assinatura do método: `protected abstract T doInBackground()` ela indica que deve retornar `T` que é o tipo indicado no primeiro parâmetro de `SwingWorker<T,V>`.

Comment: Como você é obrigado a indicar o tipo dos parâmetros ao instanciar *SwingWorker*, se não há nada para retornar do método `doInBackground()` usa-se o tipo `Void`.