# Passagem de argumentos opcionais em Java

Tags: java, swing, método, swingworker

Estou tentando aprender o funcionamento da classe [**`SwingWorker<T,V>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), já até fiz [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119227/m%C3%A9todo-exige-retorno-mesmo-tendo-void-na-assinatura) a respeito de um de seus métodos.

Olhando o código fonte desta classe, encontrei o método `publish()` escrito da seguinte forma:

```
SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs") // Passing chunks to add is safe
    protected final void publish(V... chunks) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (doProcess == null) {
                doProcess = new AccumulativeRunnable<V>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(List<V> args) {
                        process(args);
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void submit() {
                        doSubmit.add(this);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        doProcess.add(chunks);
    }
```

Na "assinatura" do método, ele recebe `V... chunks` como argumento. Porém, após testar um pouco esta classe, notei que, mesmo se eu definir esse tipo `V` na hora de iniciar uma variável, exemplo `SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker;`(O `V` é representado pelo `Integer`), e passar o `publish()` sem parâmetro, não é gerado erro de sintaxe, e o código funciona normalmente.

Diante do exposto, questiono: como é denominado essa forma de passar argumentos sem que sejam obrigatórios e como a JVM trata esse tipo de método?

Comment: Relacionada? [O que significam as reticências nos parâmetros de um método?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46174/4808)

Comment: @renan o "varargs" escrito bem ali em cima kkkkk Mas não sabia que era o nome desse tipo de passagem de parâmetro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essencialmente está respondido na [pergunta do Renan Gomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46174/101). E é bom que se diga que o parâmetro não é opcional, os argumentos é que podem ser ([veja a diferença entre eles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)).

Como no fundo os argumentos são encapsulados em um *array* que é o parâmetro, a variável do parâmetro sempre existirá, portanto nunca haverá erro. Se não passar nenhum argumento, o *array*, no caso, `chuncks` terá zero elementos, mas ainda será um *array*.

Pense se o *varargs* não existisse, a sintaxe seria assim:

```
void publish(V[] chunks)
```

e as chamadas poderiam ser assim:

```
obj.publish(new V[] {1, 2, 3});
obj.publish(new V[] {});
```

Com este açúcar sintático, pode ser assim:

```
obj.publish(1, 2, 3);
obj.publish();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Params.java).

Não é mais simples?