# Como usar JProgressBar em classes de comparação de ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Tenho uma classe que compara dois `ArrayList`, um com informações adicionadas pelo usuário e outro com consulta do banco de dados.

Depois que a consulta é feita, mando este objeto para outra classe que realiza a escrita desses dados em um arquivo. Gostaria que, enquanto estas verificações fossem feitas, mostrasse um `JProgressBar` pra o usuário não ter a impressão de que o sistema está travado.

```
public ArrayList<ModeloCadastroTerceiro> verificaCodigoTerceiro(ArrayList<ModeloCadastroTerceiro> modelo) {

    ConectaBanco conecta = new ConectaBanco();

  conecta.conexao();
  StringBuilder str_busca = new StringBuilder(); 

    ArrayList<ModeloCadastroTerceiro> modeloRetorno = new ArrayList<>();

    ModeloCadastroTerceiro mod;

    str_busca.append('(');
    for (ModeloCadastroTerceiro modelo1 : modelo) {
        str_busca.append("'");
        str_busca.append(modelo1.getCpfTerceiro());
        str_busca.append("'");
        str_busca.append(',');
    }

    str_busca.deleteCharAt((str_busca.toString().length() - 1));

    str_busca.append(')');

    String busca = String.valueOf(str_busca);

    conecta.executaSQL("select * from cadastro_terceiros where cpf_cnpj_terceiro in" + busca);

    try {
        conecta.rs.first();

        do {
            mod = new ModeloCadastroTerceiro();
            mod.setCodTerceiro(conecta.rs.getInt("id_prosoft_terceiro"));
            mod.setCpfTerceiro(conecta.rs.getString("cpf_cnpj_terceiro"));
            modeloRetorno.add(mod);
        } while (conecta.rs.next());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        if (ex.getErrorCode() == 0) {

        } else {
            Logger.getLogger(RecuperaInformacaoBanco.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

   ArrayList<ModeloCadastroTerceiro> fim = new ArrayList<>();
    ModeloCadastroTerceiro modFim;

    for (ModeloCadastroTerceiro mod1 : modelo) {

        boolean flag = false;//usada para marcar terceiro não encontrado

        for (ModeloCadastroTerceiro te1 : modeloRetorno) {

            if (mod1.getCpfTerceiro().equals(te1.getCpfTerceiro())) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (flag == false) {
            modFim = new ModeloCadastroTerceiro();
            modFim.setCodTerceiro(mod1.getCodTerceiro());
            modFim.setNomeTerceiro(mod1.getNomeTerceiro());
            modFim.setCpfTerceiro(mod1.getCpfTerceiro());
            fim.add(modFim);
        }else{
            System.out.println("TERCEIRO JA CADASTRADO... NÃO SERA IMPORTADO");
        }

    }
    return fim;
}
```

Depois disso eu chamo a classe que escreve no arquivo a partir de um `ArrayList`

```
public void escreverNoArquivo(File arquivo, ArrayList<String> texto) {

    FileWriter fw;
    BufferedWriter bw;

    try {

        fw = new FileWriter(arquivo);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        // Recupera cada linha do texto e escreve no arquivo
        for (int i = 0; i < texto.size(); i++) {

            // Escreve o texto no arquivo
            bw.write(texto.get(i));
            // Quebra de linha
            bw.newLine();

        }

        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Como fazer um `JProgressBar` que mostre o andamento disso?

Comment: A progress vai aparecer quando?

Comment: A ideia é que aparece quando estiver escrevendo no arquivo... Realizando o processo pra gera-lo do inicio ao fim.

Comment: Então a progressbar deve seguir o andamento do método `escreverNoArquivo`?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uso da classe [**`SwingWorker`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), colocando nela a execução do método em paralelo a execução da tela.

```
public void escreverNoArquivo(File arquivo, ArrayList<String> texto) {

    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {

        //executará a ação em uma thread paralela a EDT
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            FileWriter fw;
            BufferedWriter bw;
            fw = new FileWriter(arquivo);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            // Recupera cada linha do texto e escreve no arquivo
            for (int i = 0; i < texto.size(); i++) {
                // Escreve o texto no arquivo
                bw.write(texto.get(i));
                //publica a atualização para a progressbar
                // através do método process(List<type> chunks)
                publish(i);
                // Quebra de linha
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
            return null;
        }

        //carrega a progressbar a medida que o publish
        //envia o andamento do doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            int progress = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            suaProgressBar.setValue(progress);
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                //captura o retorno do doInBackground
                //mas neste caso, apenas retorna se houver alguma
                //exceção lançado na execução do doInBackground
                get();
                //reseta o progresso, já que a execução terminou
                progressBar.setValue(0);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(progressBar.getParent(),"Terminou!");
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    //executa a ação anterior.
    worker.execute();
}
```

> Obs.: Como se trata de uma execução em classe anônima, **suaProgressBar** deve ser uma variável da sua classe de tela, ou caso seja local, deverá ser final, senão não será possível acessá-la dentro do *swingWorker*, da forma como foi apresentado.

Caso se interesse em saber mais sobre o funcionamento e uso do `SwingWorker`, eis alguns links que podem ajudar:

- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker(Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [Passar a execução de um determinado método para o SwingWorker como argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120325/28595)
- [Métodos que exigem retorno mesmo tendo Void na "assinatura"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119227/28595)
- [Capturar exceções na execução do swingworker](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124867/28595)
- [Passagem de argumentos opcionais em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119541/28595)

Comment: Cara sei que já faz  muito tempo, mas só consegui testar agora. Estou com uma dúvida no método protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            int progress = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            suaProgressBar.setValue(progress);
        }, não é chamado momento algum e esta dando erro de "type List does not take parameters". sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: @Valdecir Quem chama o método process é o método publish(), veja que inseri ele dentro do laço. Agora quanto ao erro, veja se você não importou erroneamente a classe `java.awt.List` ao invés de `java.util.List`.

Comment: Cara 2 vezes no mesmo dia? rsrs Obrigado mesmo ajudou novamente e muito!