# Erro NullPointerException, onde está o erro?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Eu queria saber onde está o erro. Eu li que o erro `NullPointerException` é quando tentamos acessar uma variavél que não foi inicializada, só não achei esse erro no meu código.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public  class NovoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     PreparedStatement stl;
     ResultSet rs;
     Connection con;



    public NovoJFrame() {
        initComponents();

        IniciarBD();

        this.PrencherComboBox();

        jPanel3.setVisible(false);
    }


    public void PrencherComboBox(){
        String sql = "Select * from ALUNO";
        try {

               stl = con.prepareStatement(sql);
               rs = stl.executeQuery();

               while(rs.next()){
                   jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("NOME"));
               }
           } catch(SQLException ex){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
           }

    }





    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(java.awt.Color.blue);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 255));
        jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 51));

        jLabel6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/liceu terras.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(265, 265, 265)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31))
        );

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Visualizar Tempo");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/med grande.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(61, 61, 61))
        );

        jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Aluno:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Quantidade:");

        jComboBox2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Adicionar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 0));
        jLabel5.setText("Com Sucesso");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 0));
        jLabel4.setText("Operação Realizada");

        jLabel8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/simbolo dinheiro.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                .addGap(115, 115, 115))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addGap(51, 51, 51))))))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Status");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(116, 116, 116))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton3))
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)))
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jPanel3.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        med frame = new med();  

        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {         






            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NovoJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   


    private void IniciarBD(){

        try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Erro :" + e.getMessage() );
    }

    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bd" ;
    String user = "root" ;
    String pass = "senha" ;


        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, user, pass );

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            System.out.println("Conexão Realizada com Sucesso");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro :" + e.getMessage() );
        }

}
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at NovoJFrame.PrencherComboBox(NovoJFrame.java:43)
at NovoJFrame.<init>(NovoJFrame.java:33)
at NovoJFrame$3.run(NovoJFrame.java:280)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Nem tem como reproduzir o problema com esse código que postou. Então, em que linha é apontada a exceção?

Comment: Exato. É necessário informar o stack trace da exceção, com a linha onde ocorre o erro. À primeira vista, a exceção pode estar ocorrendo por conta das variáveis "con", "jPanel3" ou "jComboBox1", que não temos certeza se foram inicializadas. Outra coisa, seu SQL está com o "*" colado no "from", dê um espaço no meio deles.

Comment: "*li que o erro `NullPointerException` é quando tentamos acessar uma variavél que não foi inicializada*" - Não exatamente, veja mais [nesta minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/132). Além disso, o seu código está incompleto e não tem o stacktrace, e por causa disso faltam informações essenciais na sua pergunta para que alguém possa dar alguma resposta satisfatória a ela. Peço-lhe que edite a pergunta acrescentando o stacktrace e o resto do seu código, inclusive os métodos `initComponents()`, `IniciarBD()` e `PreencherComboBox()`.

Comment: Qual é a linha 43?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Pronto, mudei

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento     stl = con.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: tem como postar o NovoJFrame.java inteiro, incluindo os imports?

Answer (score 2):

O seu principal problema é que no método `PreencherComboBox`, você não inicializa a conexão.

A solução mais simples seria fazer isso:

```java
    public void PrencherComboBox(){
        String sql = "Select * from ALUNO";
        try {
               con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
               stl = con.prepareStatement(sql);
               rs = stl.executeQuery();

               while(rs.next()){
                   jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("NOME"));
               }
           } catch(SQLException ex){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
           }

    }
```

Entretanto, já que estamos aqui, podemos analisar quais outros problemas temos no seu código. E há vários deles:

- Você esqueceu o modificador `private` em alguns atributos da classe. A visibilidade de pacote provavelmente não é o que você quer.
- Você abre conexões, `Statement`s e `ResultSet`s mas não os fecha adequadamente. Isso é uma má prática que pode levar a desperdício no consumo de memória ou na manutenção de conexões abertas que já não são mais úteis. A forma mais prática de lidar com esse problema é usando a sintaxe do `try` denominada [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).
- Você mistura lógica de visualização (swing) com lógica de acesso aos dados (JDBC). Para que o código fique organizado, é melhor separá-las.
- Você não está seguindo corretamente as convenções de nomenclatura da linguagem Java. Métodos devem ter o seu nome iniciados com letra minúscula.

Vamos então resolver esses problemas todos:

```java
public class AcessoDados {
    private final String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bd";
    private final String user = "root";
    private final String pass = "senha";

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro :" + e.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public AcessoDados() {
        this.url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bd";
        this.user = "root";
        this.pass = "senha";
    }

    public AcessoDados(String url, String user, String pass) {
        this.url = url;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    private Connection conectar() {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    }

    public List<String> listarNomesDeAlunos() throws SQLException {
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>(10);

        String sql = "SELECT nome FROM ALUNO";
        try (
            Connection con = conectar();
            PreparedStatement stl = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stl.executeQuery();
        ) {
           while (rs.next()) {
               lista.addItem(rs.getString("NOME"));
           }
        }
        return lista;
    }

    public void testarConexao() throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection con = conectar();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ) {
            System.out.println("Conexão Realizada com Sucesso");
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class NovoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private final AcessoDados acesso = new AcessoDados();

    public NovoJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        jPanel3.setVisible(false);

        try {
            acesso.testarConexao();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro :" + e.getMessage());
        }

        this.prencherComboBox();
    }

    public void prencherComboBox() {
        List<String> nomes;
        try {
            nomes = acesso.listarNomesDeAlunos();
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
       }

        for (String nome : nomes) {
            jComboBox1.addItem(nome);
        }
    }

    // ... Resto da classe...
}
```

Ainda há mais um sério problema que você deve resolver. **Você está manipulando o banco de dados na mesma thread do swing.** Isso pode deixar a aplicação não-responsiva. [O motivo é que o banco de dados pode demorar um pouco para fazer a requisição, e durante esse período, a sua tela ficará congelada.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132) Para resolver isso, procure utilizar a classe [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) de forma a não deixar o swing travar por estar fazendo operações no banco de dados.

Entretanto, para propor uma solução a isso usando o `SwingWorker`, seria necessário mudar muita coisa na estrutura da sua aplicação, muito mais do que apenas o trecho do que você postou na pergunta. Além disso, esse assunto já é uma outra conversa bem longe do propósito inicial do que está delineado na pergunta. Caso tenha interesse, sugiro que faça uma nova pergunta acerca deste tópico.

Comment: `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");` essa chamada é opcional se ele estiver usando jdk 7+.

Comment: Como complemento a resposta do Victor, [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130504/28595) tem um exemplo do uso do swingworker com uma barra de progresso. Claro que você precisará adaptar o doInBackground e o publish para sua necessidade.

Comment: @diegofm Sim, mas considerei três coisas: (1) isso já estava no código original do OP; (2) é inofensivo no caso de a aplicação não ter problemas com o classpath e denuncia eventuais problemas se houverem e (3) eu respondi uma pergunta aqui há uns dias atrás onde o OP tinha conseguido bagunçar com isso ao usar um driver antigo no classpath. Assim sendo, acho melhor deixar. Caso o autor da pergunta quiser, ele poder retirar o bloco `static { ... }` e deverá/deveria funcionar do mesmo jeito.

Comment: É verdade, agora que reparei que no código já estava assim.

Answer (score -3):

```
Connection con = null;

stl = con.prepareStatement(sql); // con = null
```

caso `IniciarBD()` esteja inicializando a variável `con`, então:

```
rs = stl.executeQuery();
jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("NOME"));
```

Se a execução da query falhar, `rs = null`.

Comment: Amigo, não fui eu quem negativou a sua resposta, mas confesso que não entendi exatamente o que você está propondo que o autor da pergunta faça.