# Java.Lang.NullPoinerException ao tentar inserir dados do banco em um JComboBox

Tags: java, postgresql, swing, jdbc, nullpointerexception

hoje eu e minha equipe nos deparamos com um problema ao tentar fazer algo aparentemente simples: exibir o nome  sobrenome de um funcionario em um JComboBox. O Problema é que na hora de abrir a tela recebemos de cara um NullPointerException e o Combo  fica vazio. Foi assim que fizemos:

```
 private void AddFunconarioCombo () throws Exception
 {
     PreparedStatement ps = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
try{



        String sql = "select nome_funcionario, sobrenome_funcionario from tbl_funcionario where flag_ativo =1";


        ps = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {          
            ComboNomeUsuario.removeAllItems();
            ComboNomeUsuario.addItem(rs.getString("nome_funcionario") + " " + rs.getString("sobrenome_funcionario"));


        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao buscar os dados para o cadastro de Usuários!  " + e.toString());
    }
    finally
{
    ConnectionFactory.CloseConnection(con, ps, rs);
}



 }
```

O método acima faz uma query do banco de dados que retorna os dados registrados na tabela tbl_funcionario, e depois insere no ComboBox ComboNomeUsuario, depois, eu chamo esse método no construtor da classe e no Actionlistener de um botão.
Segue também a pilha de erros:

> fev 23, 2018 4:24:31 PM view.TelaDeCadastro 
>   GRAVE: null
>   java.lang.Exception: Erro ao buscar os dados para o cadastro de Usuários!  java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at view.TelaDeCadastro.AddFunconarioCombo(TelaDeCadastro.java:1633)
>       at view.TelaDeCadastro.(TelaDeCadastro.java:104)
>       at view.Retaguarda$7.actionPerformed(Retaguarda.java:399)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

E depois disso, com faço para usar o dados desse combobox e inseri - los no banco? Segue o Código do DAO

```
public void Salvar (Usuario u) throws Exception{

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    if (u == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro: Usuario não pode ser nulo!");
    }

    try {


        String sql = "insert into tbl_usuario (id_usuario, login_usuario, senha_usuario, fk_funcionario, flag_ativo)"
                + "values (NEXTVAL('sequencia_usuario'),?,?,CURRVAL('sequencia_funcionario'),1)";

        ps = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, u.getLoginUsuario());
        ps.setString(2, u.getSenhaUsuario());


        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao inserir os dados!" + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        ConnectionFactory.CloseConnection(con, ps);
    }

}
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: O erro está no arquivo `Retaguarda.java` na linha 399, o stacktrace é bem claro.
Só com o pedaço de código fornecido não tem como ajudar.

Comment: Qual é o valor de `con` quando a execução entra no `try`?

Comment: Sei que é meio chato fechar a sua pergunta como duplicata, mas não surpreendentemente, você não foi o primeiro a cometer esse tipo de erro. O seu objeto `con` deve ser nulo, exatamente como no caso da pergunta que marquei na duplicata. Leia a [minha resposta naquela pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143511/132) que deverá te ajudar.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Era isso mesmo! Faltava Iniciar a conexão! Mas agora como faço para inserir esses dados do combo na tabela usuarios?

Answer (score 0):

Por causa do log acredito que o erro aconteça dentro da cláusula `try`. Talvez os atributos `ps` e `rs` sejam `null`, devido a algum problema na consulta SQL.

Debugar esse trecho com o uso de breakpoints irá ajudar a descobrir o que está dando errado.

Comment: É IMPOSSÍVEL um Nullpointer sair desse try catch, ele ta pegando qualquer exceção com o `Exception`.

Comment: @MaxFratane você tem razão, fiz confusão aqui e errei!